# SQL Syntax validation

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

**Here is my database structure:**

[image]

**Here is the snippet of my TimeSlot.php:**

```
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Response' => array(
        'className' => 'Response',
        'foreignKey' => 'time_slot_id`'
    )
);
```

**and Response.php:**

```
   public $belongsTo = array(
    'TimeSlot' => array(
        'className' => 'TimeSlot',
        'foreignKey' => 'time_slot_id'
    )
);
```

**When I add this line to my action in Meetings Controller:**

```
  $this->loadModel("TimeSlot");
  $time_slot = $this->TimeSlot->find("first");
  debug($time_slot);
```

**This results to:**

```
   Database Error
   Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL    syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`.`responses` AS `Response` WHERE `Response`.`time_slot_id` = (1)' at line 1

   SQL Query: SELECT `Response`.`id`, `Response`.`invitee_id`, `Response`.`time_slot_id`, `Response`.`time_slot_id`` FROM `meetingscheduler`.`responses` AS `Response` WHERE `Response`.`time_slot_id` = (1)
```

I'm a little confused whats wrong with my codes. But I think its the relations ship between TimeSlot and Response Models because once I ignore the ralationships, its working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra tick here:

```
.`time_slot_id``
             ^^^
```

Comment: Oh God. Thank you very much. I hardly noticed that one. Thanks. It took me hours. I thought I have set up the models relationship wrong. It's that damn "`" >_<